# Uboot : mount can't find root partition in /etc/fstab

Tags: debian, mount, beagleboneblack, fstab

I am on a BeagleBone Black with [Debian Jessie 8.5](http://%20%3Chttps://rcn-ee.com/rootfs/2016-06-09/flasher/BBB-eMMC-flasher-debian-8.5-console-armhf-2016-06-09-2gb.img.xz%3E)  , so the BBB boots from the eMMc.

My goal is to use SPI, but the cape manager was not available so according to [RobertCNelson](http://%3Chttps://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/IpZuVHS3aEs%3E)  , I have set the linux image 3.8.13.

Everything boots fine, but when I follow the steps to use the SPI0 described on elinux that enables spidev, it doesn't boot anymore :

```
mount : can't find /root in /etc/fstab
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
mount : mounting /dev on /root/dev failed : No such file or directory
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg
```

With Busybox and the (initramfs) prompt, I have manually mounted the `/dev/mmcblk0p1` partition on /mnt. Fstab is ok, but the `/mnt/boot/uboot` directory is empty.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix it ?

EDIT : Here is my /boot/uEnv.txt file :

```
    #Docs: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:U-boot_partitioning_layout_2.0

    uname_r=3.8.13-bone68
    ##uuid=
    #dtb=

    ##BeagleBone Black/Green dtb's for v4.1.x (BeagleBone White just works..)

    ##BeagleBone Black: HDMI (Audio/Video) disabled:
    #dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb

    ##BeagleBone Black: eMMC disabled:
    #dtb=am335x-boneblack-hdmi-overlay.dtb

    ##BeagleBone Black: HDMI Audio/eMMC disabled:
    #dtb=am335x-boneblack-nhdmi-overlay.dtb

    ##BeagleBone Black: HDMI (Audio/Video)/eMMC disabled:
    #dtb=am335x-boneblack-overlay.dtb

    ##BeagleBone Black: wl1835
    #dtb=am335x-boneblack-wl1835mod.dtb

    ##BeagleBone Green: eMMC disabled
    #dtb=am335x-bonegreen-overlay.dtb

    cmdline=coherent_pool=1M quiet cape_universal=enable

    #In the event of edid real failures, uncomment this next line:
    #cmdline=coherent_pool=1M quiet cape_universal=enable video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e

   ##Example v3.8.x
   #cape_disable=capemgr.disable_partno=
   #cape_enable=capemgr.enable_partno=

   ##Example v4.1.x
   #cape_disable=bone_capemgr.disable_partno=
   #cape_enable=bone_capemgr.enable_partno=

   ##enable Generic eMMC Flasher:
   #cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh

   #Load SPI
   optargs=quiet drm.debug=7 capemgr.enable_partno=BB-SPI0-01

   uuid=29dc1724-e732-4f02-91d1-7b206a4cb317
```

Comment: Sounds like by editing the uEnv you have broken the kernel cmdline. Double check what you did, it might be a linebreak in the wrong spot or spurious quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added my `/boot/uEnv.txt` file, the only thing that I have added are :

    `#Load SPI`
    `optargs=quiet drm.debug=7 capemgr.enable_partno=BB-SPI0-01`

but I don't see anything wrong

Comment: Note that in this case you need to see what /etc/fstab says in the initramfs and not the one on the eMMC as that's what is not finding "/root".

Comment: I have copied `/mnt/etc/fstab` to `/etc/fstab`, but after reboot the file disappeared :/